# incorrect syntax near database

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2012

There's an error saying syntax error in 'Database[DatabaseName]'

[Here is the screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rLK8n.png)

I don't know what in the query is wrong.

This is the code for this problem:

```
Private Sub btnBackUp_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnBackUp.Click
        Try
            Me.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor
            Dim Filename As String
            get_servername = cmbservername.Text.Trim
            get_userid = txtuser.Text.Trim
            get_password = txtpassword.Text.Trim
            database = cmbdatabase.Text
        If cmbauth.SelectedIndex = 0 Then
            constr = "Data Source=" & get_servername & ";Initial Catalog=" & cmbdatabase.Text & "; Integrated Security= True "
        Else
            constr = "Data Source=" & get_servername & ";Initial Catalog=" & cmbdatabase.Text & "; user id=" & get_userid & ";password=" & get_password & ";Integrated Security=false"
        End If
        con = New SqlConnection(constr)
        con.Open()
        Dim strquery As String
        Dim save_dialog As New SaveFileDialog
        save_dialog.FileName = database
        save_dialog.ShowDialog()
        Filename = save_dialog.FileName
        strquery = "BACKUP DATABASE" & database & " TO DISK ='" & Filename & "'"
        Me.Cursor = Cursors.Default
        Try
            com = New SqlCommand(strquery, con)
            data_affector = com.ExecuteNonQuery
            MessageBox.Show("Backup has been successfully created", "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
            Me.Cursor = Cursors.Default
        Catch ex As Exception
            Me.Cursor = Cursors.Default
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
            Exit Sub
        End Try
    Catch ex As Exception
        Me.Cursor = Cursors.Default
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)

    End Try

End Sub
```

Comment: `trquery = "BACKUP DATABASE" & database & " TO DISK ='" & Filename & "'"` is missing a space after DATABASE, isnt it?

Comment: You should learn to use `String.Format` or string interpolation. Also, use a `SqlConnectionStringBuilder` to build a SQL Server connection string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a space in your query

```
strquery = "BACKUP DATABASE" & database & " TO DISK ='" & Filename & "'"
```

If the value of database is `Northwinds` your query would start with `BACKUP DATABASENorthwinds`. Try updating to add a space:

```
strquery = "BACKUP DATABASE " & database & " TO DISK ='" & Filename & "'"
```

Comment: This is a perfect example of why you should always use `String.Format` or, more recently, string interpolation.  Doing so makes it easy to spot silly mistakes like this. Use `strquery = String.Format("BACKUP DATABASE {0} TO DISK = '{1}'", database, Filename)` or `strquery = $"BACKUP DATABASE {database} TO DISK = '{Filename}'"`.